# Java EE How to generate reports containing multiple entities in result

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, report, java-ee-7

Here's the abbreviated use case scenario:

1. User clicks a button, which opens the reports designer screen.
2. User selects an entity from a select list.
3. The application displays a new screen, which displays the name of the entity selected in (2) and names of all entities related to the entity selected, in horizontal fashion across the screen.
4. Beneath each entity, the application displays all fields of the entity with one check box next to each field for the user to optionally select.
5. The user clicks the Display Report button.
6. The application displays a DataTable, each column containing data from a field selected in (4).

So you can imagine this is just a simple reporting mechanism, which would generate columns from potentially several joined database tables.  That's it.  Should be pretty straightforward to implement, right?

Consider a hypothetical example of three entities related to each other: User-Role-Permission.  The user wants a report of ALL permissions assigned to each user.  The report, in tabular format, will have columns as follows:

| User.firstName | User.lastName | Role.name | Permission.name |

All of the examples I've seen as I peruse the inter-web involve one entity.  As you can see, this example has three joined entities -- and the report displays columns from all three tables.

I can use the JPA Criteria API along with dynamic entity graphs but OH what about all of those rows of entity-objects!  What if I have 500, or a thousand rows?  I can imagine that loading all of the entities might be more taxing than simply creating the data table using a result set.  Am I right?  Or should I not worry about this?  In which case the problem is resolved, and I can use the JPA Criteria API to implement this use case.  But I am concerned about performance.

Because the user needs to generate the report at runtime I presume that using Jasper Reports designer (iReports) is out of the question(?).  I should be able to complete this feature using JEE, right?  In which case am I relegated to a custom in-house solution?  Are there no libraries available for what I am trying to do?

If not, it seems that I will need to use (eghad!) ResultSets.  Is this true?

I did look through the [Hibernate documentation](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/4.3/) and didn't see anything that would help me in this endeavor.  The closest thing I found was [dynamic models](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#persistent-classes-dynamicmodels), which appear to me to require compile time configuration -- not run-time configuration.

Whatever!  Maybe there is something really simple that I'm just not seeing.  I just want to dump a load into a DataTable.  Any ideas/ insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just simply create a JPQL query fetching the needed data at once. Hibernate caching should kick in anyways. If the amount of data gets to high start using a dedicated search database like elasticsearch is not an option?

Comment: I can run a query that joins 5 tables and only selects 2 columns in the RDBMS and get a result set of 1500 rows very fast, so no worries there.  I am concerned that by using JPQL I will retrieve a list of potentially 1500 distinct objects, each object having references to other objects, just so that I can retrieve the data from two fields per row.  Intuitively seems a lot slower on the application side than simply using a result set.

Comment: Use JOIN FETCH for the sub objects you need for the further processing. This reduced the amount of later fetch operations.